# Two popup on mouse hover - addThis share button

Tags: popup, share, addthis

I run the js code as described bellow.
The result is: on share hover, the two popup appear (the promotion and the big one).
The expected result: only the small (I think it's called the promotion) popup should appear.

I already tried everything: 
1. changed to version 300, 
2. play with the window parameters set to null section (window._adr = null; ...). 
    then I have different problem, that only this lines solve.
3. and more and more and more....

also, I'm using it as part of a view/mvc

If someone handled with this problem in the past and willing to help, I will be more than thankful.

```
var addthis_config = { "data_track_clickback": true};
var script = 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#domready=1';
var posId = '<%=Model.Id%>';


var topAddThisShareSet = parseInt($('#leftContainer' + posId).prop("scrollHeight") - $('#leftContainer' + posId).prop("clientHeight"));

var addthis_config = {
    ui_offset_top: -(topAddThisShareSet),
    ui_offset_left: 0
}

debugger;
if (window.addthis)
{
    window.addthis = null;
    window._adr = null;
    window._atc = null;
    window._atd = null;
    window._ate = null;
    window._atr = null;
    window._atw = null;

}
$.getScript(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//use this to remove existing popup
$("#at20mc").remove();

if (window.addthis)
{
    window.addthis = null;
    window._adr = null;
    window._atc = null;
    window._atd = null;
    window._ate = null;
    window._atr = null;
    window._atw = null;
}
$.getScript(script);
```